# two string variables compared against a private dictionary that returns a boolean value c#

Tags: c#

I am trying to create two string variable named username and password and returns a Boolean named authenticated. I am trying to compare the username and password string against the contents of a private dictionary. If username and passwords match, I would like the Boolean to be set to true. However, I am new to c# and really don't know where to go with it. Any help would be appreciated. Below is what I already have. `

```
private Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        public Authenticator()
        {
            dictionary.Add("username1", "password1");
            dictionary.Add("username2", "password2");
            dictionary.Add("username3", "password3");
            dictionary.Add("username4", "password4");
            dictionary.Add("username5", "password5");
        }


        public Boolean Authenticate(Boolean authenticated)
        {
            //get user input 
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a username");
            string inputUsername = Console.ReadLine();

          var auth1 = from entry in dictionary
                             where entry.Key == " ";

            Console.WriteLine("Please enter your password");
            string inputPassword = Console.ReadLine();

            var auth2 = from entry in dictionary
                        where entry.Value == " ";
                         `
```

Comment: a function cannot return a variable. it returns an expression. you have to supply it username and password and use the function. in your code, you don't do anything of that sort.

Comment: try something like if(dictionary.ContainsKey(inputUserName) && dictionary[inputUserName] == inputPassword) return true; else return false; You don't need linq for that.

Comment: Side note: storing *passwords* as plain `string`s is not a good idea; a better implementation is to store and compare *passwords hashes*.

Comment: FYI Most people use the `bool` alias instead of `Boolean`, as a matter of style.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
    public bool Authenticate()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter a username");
        string inputUsername = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter your password");
        string inputPassword = Console.ReadLine();
        return dictionary.ContainsKey(inputUsername) && dictionary[inputUsername] == inputPassword;
    }
```

Comment: Well done for spotting that the parameter `authenticated` was not necessary - it may help the OP to explain why (they seem to be confused)

Comment: @Jamiec, I excluded the `authenticated` argument to provide the simplest answer to the question posed.  I leave it to the OP to expand upon the answer if he/she wants to add functionality to the method (like short-circuiting if authentication has already been performed).

Comment: @Lorek, thanks so much! and yeah I do need the Boolean authenticated but I think I have sorted that out anyway.